# how can I manage users in asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying out the asp.net identity, one thing I cannot find is a way to manage all registered users,edit them and assign roles for them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This [url](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Identity-Manager-using-ASPNET-Identity) helps you to configure Identity manager in Asp.net